# Google Maps v3 panTo() from getCenter() lat lng doesn't go to same location

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using getCenter() to use the lat lng in a url so users can share / bookmark a location on Google Maps. I then use panTo() to try and jump back to the same location. Though it always jumps back to approximately the same location it's never exactly the same view.

I've thought about using setCenter() instead of panTo() but this can mess up the referencing calculation for the custom map layer I'm displaying. Depends where the center happens to be.

To see the problem in action you can go to http://www.topomap.co.nz/ and use the "Share" tab to get a url generated from getCenter(). Using the url you'll notice they show slightly different centers.

Please note that I'm currently using latLng.toUrlValue() which reduces some of the accuracy, but you can manually tweak the url from the individual lat long given in the "Share" tab and you'll still see the same problem.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Could you explain the problem with setCenter() vs panTo() in more detail? The end result for both of them should be the same.

Comment: Hi plexer, I find that using setCenter can affect the calculations for serving up my custom map tiles if the user has selected a location to the east of New Zealand which crosses the Prime Meridian / 180° longitude line between New Zealand and the Chatham Islands. A similar affect can be achieved by scrolling www.topomap.co.nz east or west until you reach NZ again - the custom map tiles won't be visible. I'm trying to work out how to tweak the calculations to allow this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems panTo() is no substitute for setCenter(). I just have to code around my Prime Meridian issue and use setCenter() instead.

Comment: For anyone that stumbles upon this question due to having the same issue with crossing the Prime Meridian with Google Maps API v3 a work-around is provided here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2203

Answer (score 0):

You may get the bounds of the map using map.getBounds() before transition and then when you need to get back to this view use

```
fitBounds(bounds:LatLngBounds)
```

or

```
panToBounds(latLngBounds:LatLngBounds)
```

Don't know if it will work, give it a try...
Found here.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map

Comment: Thanks for the input vishwanath, however I'm hoping to only require a single lat long in the url. There's already a lot of urls out there in the wild using the map center method so didn't really want to change the url structure unless really required. Cheers.